# Generalization of boolean logic on intervals

Tags: boolean-algebra, interval-arithmetic

I'm working on a generalization of Boolean algebra in a way that it can encompass 'series' of **true**/**false** values. My motivation is to introduce logic gates which are mapping from $\{0, 1\}^n$ to $\{0, 1\}^n$; for example, generalized OR gate would map [1 1 0 1] and [1 0 0 0] to [1 1 0 1]. Long term goal would be to create a customizable network (build from those logic gates) which extracts intervals of interest.

I read about [Allen's interval algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allen%27s_interval_algebra), but as far as I understand, it's purpose is temporal reasoning and not the computation itself. Is there any already established mathematical framework which introduces structures/notions of this 'generalization' of Boolean algebra?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: The product of different Boolean algebras is itself a Boolean algebra, with the operators acting coordinatewise, and so covered by the standard theory.  Is your generalization different therefrom?

Comment: @JacobManaker Yes, but I'm also looking whether additional operators (gates) were introduced in this context. For example, like in interval temporal logic.